# winston logger not working in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

when logger is being exported to a new file it does not create a log,
I have two files

1] abc.js

```
let winston = require('winston');require('winston-logrotate');

var logger = new winston.Logger({
    level: 'info',
    transports: [
      new (winston.transports.File)({ filename: 'somefile.log' })
    ]
  });
module.exports = logger;
```

2] app.js

```
const logger = require('./abc');

logger.info("is it working"); // not change is made in the log file after this command
console.log(logger); // this is working
```

Comment: Not sure what to tell you but it works perfectly fine for me. Are you sure you're looking at the right logfile? I have it open in VS Code, and when I run `node app.js`, a new line gets added right in front of my eyes.

Comment: The code you posted works absolutely fine. `somefile.log` is beeing created (and filled) in the calling directory (right beneath app.js) as also https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g mentioned. Do you get any error messages? Can you maybe also give details about versions of node, winston, ...

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue this evening. However, I realized the file location wasn't being resolved. Remember to import path :)

```
filename: path.resolve(__dirname, "add_your_relative_path/error.log")
```